# How to use [(ngModel)] on <input type="color"> in a material dialog?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

**My problem**:
When I try to use ngModel on a color-input-element in a material-dialog I got the following warning message in chrome:

```
The specified value "" does not conform to the required format.  The format is "#rrggbb" where rr, gg, bb are two-digit hexadecimal numbers.
```

What did I wrong? Or is this a bug from Angular6?

**My Code**:

*color.html*

```html
<input type="color" [(ngModel)]="color" />
```

*app.component.html*

```html
<button (click)="openDialog()">Open Color Dialog</button>
```

*app.component.ts*

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }


  openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ColorDialogComponent);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-color',
  templateUrl: 'color.html',
})
export class ColorDialogComponent {

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AppComponent>) { }

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

}
```

Comment: Seems to work when I try? What about when you try this StackBlitz? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kxclqf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a9mipm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html. Post a complete minimal example, as I just did, but which reproduces the problem.

Comment: It works fine on Stackblitz. Kindly recreate the scenario so that we can look into it.

Comment: I reproduced that issue on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-dialog-issue the warning is caused by using material dialog.

Comment: Strange indeed. The warning appears in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the error, It's a warning actually. It should work fine, worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've spend some time with this issue and I've concluded it's a bug.

No matter how you initalize the ngModel value it always behaves like this.

Try using FormControl

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-color-input',
  templateUrl: './color-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./color-input.component.scss']
})
export class ColorInputComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('colorInputEl') colorInputEl: ElementRef;
  colorInput: FormControl = new FormControl('#000000');

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.colorInput.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
      this.colorChanged(value);
    });
  }
  ...
}
```

```html
  <input #colorInputEl [formControl]="colorInput" matInput type="color"
    placeholder="Choose Color" />
```

I added in the element reference incase you need it to trigger click or something.